# How to remove coma from last item in loop?

Tags: python

I have a loop where I print list items with commas. I want to use a comma with all items except for the last one. how do I do this?

```py
digits = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in digits:
   print(f'{i},')
```

Comment: Instead of for loop you can use ```join``` function

Answer (score 2):

You should use `str.join`:

```
print(','.join(f'{i}' for i in digits))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in digits:
    if(i == len(digits)):
        print(f'{i}')
    else:
        print(f'{i},')
```

Comment: If the last element is not 5 then this code will not work

Comment: What are you talking about? Yes it will... I can't even replicate what you mean.

Comment: for input:
digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] 
your code will print: 
1,
2,
3,
4,
6,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun example using the index!

```py
digits = [1,2,3,4,5]
output = ""
for i in range(len(digits)):
    output += str(digits[i])
    if digits[i] != digits[-1]:
        output += ", "
print(output)
```

Fun fact, this will actually work with a list of any length, except 1, and even if the elements of the list are strings, or different ints than the example ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the last elemnt :

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in digits:
    if i == digits[len(digits)-1]:
        print(f'{i}')
    else:
        print(f'{i},')
```

for string same code will do:

```
digits =  ['ali', 'khan', 'malang', 'new', 'baby'] 
for i in digits:
    if i == digits[len(digits)-1]:
        print(f'{i}')
    else:
        print(f'{i},')
```

output:

```
ali,
khan,
malang,
new,
baby
```

Comment: it works on digits but not on string... why?

Comment: stars = ['ali', 'khan', 'malang', 'new', 'baby']
for i in stars:
    if i == len(stars):
        print(f"&lt;a href='https://hdmoviesplus.gq/search/label/f'&gt;{i}&lt;/a&gt; ")
    else:
        print(f"&lt;a href='https://hdmoviesplus.gq/search/label/f'&gt;{i}&lt;/a&gt;, ")

Comment: this is my code

Comment: the code I have answered also works for string

Comment: I have added an string example , the code you commented will not work because you checked item with length in if i == len(stars)